# Korean Equties: Saving Tick Data using Win32com.Dispatch.WithEvents. Is this possible? [Python]

Tags: database

[image]

Hello, I am currently using a Korean API feed that requires win32com.Dispatch.WithEvent method to subscribe to their tick data feed. (Win32com method was the sample they gave me).

This code works well when printing (time and price) of the tick data on the console. However, I want to save the timestamp and tickdata into a List and/or to a MySQL database.

Is there an alternative to implementing the aforementioned code without the use of Win32come.Dispatch.Withevent method?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Hi Charles Shin, welcome to Quant.SE! I don't understand: If you can print them, you should also be able to save them?

Comment: Hi Bob! I
If I delete everything under Def OnReceived(self): and typed in print(inst.GetHeaderValue(18)) then the data will start to flow in and will be printed in my console. 

However, instead of print I used list.append(inst.GetHeaderValue(18)), but nothing shows up in my variable explorer. I tried to refresh the variable explorer to see if the data was being stored into the List, but nothing.

Comment: In that case, I believe you will be better served by SO in that case as this seems to be a programming peculiarity.